# Type inference in generic function-parameter types

Tags: typescript

I want to have "utility" createModel function, which infer types and I will not need to write types when i will use it.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzVYAQxmAFkIATYAGwB4BlAGjgEE5QSUKBnOACm4AuOEzhgA-MMIoAngEo4AXgB8I5XwDeAKDi64AW0o1GOvYQzYU3EwF9h2vQaPVhTU7vNYcQ1lpsKHPQIYJChcQMcnKmoTSI8Lb3c4Gz8tLRgZMGA4ABVyaKU4CLgUQn1gYW4YKEwUAHMkzG4WCwA3CrgAIwgIaiIUVK00b3hDaOE850Li0vLhAHJ52L0mlqx24QRCam5gQeGreAAlQvwiEnyaTSSxmmFbmKTPSx8+B+YwBRV+YscAOgB7ySjnKMEIwjAy10-lsciAA)

#### Code

```
 // - here A extends (s: S, p?: any) => S - we want to return our "model" type  as result 
export function createModel<S, A extends (s: S, p?: any) => S>({ 
    model,
    actions,
}: {
    model: S,
    actions: A
}) {
    return {
       model,
       actions
    }
}

type TModel = {
    name: string
    isActive: boolean
}

const model: TModel = {
    name: '',
    isActive: false
}

const R = createModel({
    model: model,
    actions: (model, p) => ({ // - model is TModel model here and its what i expect.
        ...model,
        meta: p,  // - here i return invalid model field, and haven't error, i expect TypeError
    }),
})



// if i delete spread,  it's works  - i have TypeError
const R = createModel({
    model: model,
    actions: (model, p) => ({ // - Type '{ meta: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'TModel': name, isActive
        meta: p, 
    }),
})




// if try to return primitive (for example - number), it's works  - i have TypeError
export function createModel<S, A extends (s: S, p?: any) => number>({  ......

const R = createModel({
    model: model,
    actions: (model, p) => ({ // - Type '{ meta: any; name: string; isActive: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.
        ...model,
        meta: p, 
    }),
})
```

#### Actual behavior

In "action" function  i have types this function return, and this does not depend on the types specified in createModel.

#### Expected behavior

In "action" function  i have return type what i define in generic of createModel function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the way Typescript works. Typescript doesn't check if an object is **exactly** the type you want it to be, but rather it checks if it is **compatible** with the type you want.

So let's say that we have this interface:

```js
interface IFoo {
    boo: string;
    loo: number;
}
```

Any object that has a property `boo` that is a string and a property `loo` that is a number, for Typescript will be of type `IFoo`.

eg:

```js
// This works
const obj1: IFoo = {
    boo: "Bla bla",
    foo: 2
}

// This works too (we just added a property, so it's still compatible)!
const obj2: IFoo = {
    boo: "Bla bla",
    foo: 2,
    goo: [1,2,3]
}

// This doesn't work though (Missing property)!
const obj3: IFoo = {
    boo: "Bla bla"
}
```

Here, what you are actually doing is that you have created an object that has the properties of `model` and an extra property `meta`. So, Typescript, correctly, doesn't throw a TypeError because the types are compatible (just like the aforementioned `obj2`).

```js
const R = createModel({
    model: model,
    actions: (model, p) => ({ // - model is TModel model here and its what i expect.
        ...model,
        meta: p,  // - here i return invalid model field, and haven't error, i expect TypeError
    }),
})
```

There is a workaround to achieve what you want (and an explanation for this feature) [here](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-match-the-exact-object-shape/) if you want to implement it:

```js
type ValidateStructure<T, Struct> = 
  T extends Struct ? 
  Exclude<keyof T, keyof Struct> extends never ? T : never : never;

export function createModel<S, T extends S>({ 
    model,
    actions,
}: {
    model: S,
    actions: (s: S, p?: any) => ValidateStructure<T, S>
}) {
    return {
       model,
       actions
    }
}
```

---

We should also say that you don't need to define the extra Generic Type A. You can just put the type directly on your interface.

```js
export function createModel<S>({ 
    model,
    actions,
}: {
    model: S,
    actions: (s: S, p?: any) => S
}) {
    return {
       model,
       actions
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation!ValidateStructure solved my problem.
But i need to notice, example with interface IFoo - working in another way
[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDED2nkG8BQyRyARtgFzIDOYUoA5gNyHEwXIgCuAtidMwF98+APQjkAFQAWwKsgDumKAGsq+BJhA1kmEgCsAjJQzZkAXjwsiZTJQBEAIQA2cUi7sAaK8ja3kAJnwhUXFpWQUlVWQwUwAKeRQ9Tm04ABNUiFTkVwAHKEwc6DAATw9qHGAwAHI5GmAnJ2QNbhy4MGASJwgASgBCdU1tXT1-YywcCwJiUnZHFzc4T29fSn8vafp2AG0DDzWAZgBdIOExSRk5VMwIKhAqsAiVaKlMTnopZFiAWVkqBmQ8gUisU+gMtA9hvsxqZJt4bPZnK5OosgkA).Maybe it works it that way only for generics?